# Migrated questions from closed sites link to real pages on the closed site

Tags: bug, migration, closed-sites

File this under "Bug or Feature?", but Cog Sci got  [this migration from Economics.](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/810/game-theory-strategies-to-overcome-holdout-problem) Economics is closed. Now if you click the "migrated from" link on Cog Sci, you get 
[the actual question on Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/493/game-theory-strategies-to-overcome-holdout-problem?noredirect=1) in full, as if the site weren't closed. If you go to any other page on Economics, you're redirected to the "closed" page on Area 51, which is normally what links to closed sites give you.

Interestingly, [rejected migrations](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/808/are-prostitution-and-marriage-substitutes) (post now deleted) work the same; it appears the closed economics site "got back" that [closed question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/688/are-prostitution-and-marriage-substitutes?noredirect=1) (post is "live").

Apparently the `?noredirect=1` query string to get to other *questions* on closed sites works, but it doesn't work for the non-question pages like the FAQ, log in, ect. This struck me as a possible bug, definitely weird.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131086/178438

Comment: @TimManishEarth Ahah, so it is intentional it seems

Comment: Yep, though I'm confused about the rejected migrations.

Comment: Seems like a side-effect of how site closures were done this time around. (We changed things up a bit.) Not sure if it's intentional, though.

Comment: I read your last sentence as implying that this didn't work for questions that hadn't been migrated, but [they do](http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-differences-between-the-austrian-and-keynesian-schools-of-economic?noredirect=1) [seem to](http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-are-the-major-causes-of-the-great-moderation?noredirect=1) [be available](http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-do-studies-say-about-the-length-and-causes-of-the-innovation-adoption-lag?noredirect=1). I guess you were just referring to the rest of the site.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I just tried a random page actually and found it did redirect...it appears questions do work

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since this was asked and some things have changed -- including that there's (again?) an Economics site, so your example isn't broken any more.

I just checked a [question that was migrated to Writing from a now-closed private beta](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/33587/1993), and clicking on the "migrated from" link takes me to the Area 51 page for the closed site.  I'm pretty sure I've seen that behavior before, though I don't have examples handy.  Any site that actually gets closed now started out as an Area 51 proposal, so I would expect this to work for all migrations from dead sites -- no dead links, but you also don't get to the original question because the site's not there any more.