# Badge for participation in multiple Stack Exchange networks

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

First question on meta, be nice :)

Here's the idea, basically we currently have the Convention badge, that's there in part I guess to encourage people over here and participate in the community. I propose that we have another set of badges that award people for participating in multiple communities in the Stack Exchange Network.

The idea for the new badge could follow that of the Convention badge and require 10 posts with a score of 2, but requiring that for say, 3-4 different Stack Exchange sites.

Possible badge names/success criteria:

- **Chameleon (bronze)** - 2 posts with a score of 2 on 4 networks
- **Adaptable (silver)** - 5 posts with a score of 2 on 4 networks
- **Multi-Talented (gold)** - 10 posts with a score of 2 on 4 networks

Comment: Those numbers are far too low.

Comment: @ChrisF yeah they are subjective. Wondering what other people would suggest for the actual criteria :)

Comment: `First question on meta, be nice :)` We are always nice! +1 since I already meet the requirements for gold.

Comment: And where would these badges would be awarded? All participating sites?

Comment: @Oded yeah all of them I think it makes sense to do it that way, kinda simliar in a way to Autobiographer, you automatically get that on account creation on another site because it is imported from SO?

Comment: @mattytommo - Well, that gets copied and _if_ complete you get the badge (which is still individual to the site).

Comment: @ChrisF you got a suggestion on the numbers? :)

Comment: I thought there was only one stackexchange network.

Comment: @Won't maybe that's not the correct terminology, but I was referring to the different sites such as webmasters.stackexchange.com and math.stackexchange.com I assumed they were *StackExchange networks*, but I guess they are *StackExchange sites* :)

Comment: @mattytommo: Hmm, I failed to enrage you with my snark.  I shall try again another day.  Until then, fare thee well.

Comment: @Won't haha maybe try on a Monday, dude it's Friday afternoon so even if you virtually bitchslapped me right now you couldn't wipe the smile off my face :D

Comment: Don't give him any ideas...

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75257/stack-exchange-badges)

Comment: See answer here, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253982/13295

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would have to be off-site. See a good implementation at

[Stackathlon 2.5: Leader board for users active on multiple sites](https://stackapps.com/questions/885/stackathlon-users-active-on-all-three-of-so-sf-and-su)

We looked at this as a possible enhancement to the reputation leagues:

https://stackexchange.com/leagues

But nothing other than StackAthlon does cross-site awarding. For what it's worth, **it is exceedingly rare for any given user to have high rep (say, 2k+) on multiple sites**, so if you do achieve this, you are exceptional almost by definition.

The rareness of this is one reason why we didn't pursue a deeper native StackAthlon, though I love the idea, and the [Bruce Jenners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Jenner#Olympic_career) of our network.

http://www.halloffamememorabilia.com/images/products/p-408318-bruce-jenner-autographed-8x10-photo-olympic-decathlon-jsa-image-1-aw-34069.jpg

Possibly related: back in April 2010 we proposed some badges that worked at the "whole site" level, that is, the *site itself* would earn badges relative to its peers in the network. But we kind of shelved that idea.

Comment: So how many such exceptional people are there?

Comment: @Gilles I like to think we're all exceptional.

Comment: @keen some are more exceptional than others. Someone should probably build an app that enhances StackAthlon so we can find these multi-site savants easier. Surely it's possible with the SE API 2.0...

Answer (score 19):

I like it but there's a tiny tiny problem: On what site would the badge be awarded to?

We currently have no notion of network badges, but as the network grows I think we should start thinking about network wide badges and other types of network wide recognition. One use case this might be useful would be for all our friends that participated in [closed betas](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/), a network wide badge might only be a very small recognition of their hard work, but it's better than nothing.

Anyways, I like the names, but as @ChrisF mentioned your numbers are *very* low.

Comment: Hmm, well I'm not sure how the badge awarding system works currently, but couldn't it just poll the network accounts to get the information? Kind of similar to how it works on your accounts page in StackOverflow. It should be awarded on all participating sites I guess.

Comment: @mattytommo Well awarding the badge on all sites is one possible solution, but that would mess up things like the [combined flair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116/should-combined-flair-be-offered), the total badge count would be off. It's one thing to get the same badge on all sites, and quite another to have people believing you have more badges than you have actually earned. Certainly the combined flair could be tweaked to only count net badges once, but that sounds too much trouble for what it's worth.

Comment: The closed beta people get to keep certain vote-related badges.

Comment: @Manishearth Interesting. Keep them where?

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast Yeah whilst I agree it is more trouble that it's worth, but it opens the doors for the possibility of other badges of the cross-network nature :)

Comment: @mattytommo That's why I upvoted your question, and took the time to answer. ;P

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast: Let me reword that. `Users on the closed betas which are being merged with Physics get to transfer certain vote-related badges on Physics` . See "As a member of one of the sites to be migrated, what do I need to do?" section [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/what-do-you-need-to-know-about-the-upcoming-mass-migration)

Comment: @Manishearth Ah, that's very specific and it only applies to people involved with questions that were successfully salvaged, and unfortunately they are a very small minority of the total crowds of the closed betas.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast: Nope. Not for Astro and TP.SE. All the posts are being migrated, except for astrophotography (to photo.SE), and quantum computing(to cstheory.SE) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130342/salvage-questions-on-closed-sites-via-migration So that's nearly all the posts, and it's likely that you get to keep the badges.

Comment: @Manishearth I like it that Astro was mostly salvaged, but there were 5 other betas closed, and there were others before them and there will be others in the future. Is there a point in continuing this discussion? I already know you helped salvaging Astro, and I upvoted your relevant Meta questions, but I get the feeling you are spamming me a bit now...

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast: Sorry if you though it was spamming :(  I sort of just wanted to point out that it was not _completely_ true that the closed beta people lose their badges. Just posting the links since I didn't want to re-explain :/ .

Comment: @Manishearth No worries, spamming wasn't the best word to use there. In any case, the badges people keep from their work on Astro are now Physics/Photography badges, what I had in mind was more like a badge saying: "I was one of the brave few of Astro.SE", on the top contributors' network profile.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast: Aah, I get it.. Yeah, nework-wide badges in general is a nice idea. I, for one would get the [Too Much Time On MSO] badge ;-) .